# Wrong total number of pages in page numbering

Tags: floats, page-numbering

My document is 39 pages long. However, the total page number (after numerous processing) is 36. I thus have page 1/36, 2/36, ... 36/36, as well as 37/36, 38/36, and 39/36.

Page 36 matches with the end of my text: the end of page 36 and pages 37 to 39 are filled with (floating) tables only.
If I add enough content in order to have regular text displayed after all floating tables, the numbering becomes right, i.e., the total page number equals 39.

[image]

I have tried to add `\null` after the last floating table, but it has no effect.

The total number of pages is computed via the `\@totpages` variable that is defined as following in the `.cls` file I use. (This class is the template of the journal I want to publish in, based on the `article` class.)

```
\def\@totpages{0}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\@totpages{\thepage}}}
```

**Question:** How to force the total of page number to be compute *after* the last float being printed?

Comment: If needed, I can provide a MWE, but I use an exotic class pimped by the journal I want to publish in. So maybe the solution is so obvious, I do not have to create such example ! N.B.: The exotic class is based on `article`, and loads `morefloats`, as well as `stfloats` floats packages.

Comment: Do you use the lastpage package to get the label?

Comment: Your comment made me browse class definition - what is indeed a good idea to understand how is totalpage generated! Anyway, the footer is defined as `\thepage/\@totpages` where `\@totpages` is computed as following: first `\def\@totpages{0}` and then `\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\@totpages{\thepage}}}` (all these commands are in class definition)

Comment: load lastpage and then redefine the footer to use \pageref{LastPage}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: `\RequirePackage{lastpage}` + `\def\@totpages{\pageref{LastPage}}` does the job! Would you mind writing an answer I could accept? (My next issue is to let my modifications be accepted by journal editor!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Load the `lastpage` package and then redefine the footer or `\@totpages` to use `\pageref{LastPage}`.

The lastpage package tries very hard to get the correct last page number even if there are pending floats and so is much more reliable than most manual solutions.