# Fix total number of pages in beamer

Tags: beamer, counters, slideshow

I am working on a `beamer` file that has a a lot of slides as an "appendix". Hence, when I introduce the command `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]` to display the page progress in the footer I get the outcome `1/200`. I would like to know if there is a command that can fix the count to stop when I reach those "appendix slides". Meaning I would see `1/10` and then, just no count. There are a few questions on numbering that I have reviewed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567058/total-number-of-pages-of-section) and [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227/how-can-i-add-page-of-on-my-document), but I was not able to successfully adapt their code.

Another approach that I tried was found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314012/wrong-total-number-of-pages-in-page-numbering): using the [`lastpage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) package with the command `\pageref{LastPage}`. However, it did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`appendixnumberbeamer`](https://ctan.org/pkg/appendixnumberbeamer) package does not count appendix slides, provided that the beginning of the appendix is declared with the `\appendix` command. See also [Don't count backup slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70448/dont-count-backup-slides).